# Add one more total row to mdx

Tags: database, mdx, cube

I have a cube with members amount (measure group) and 3 dimensions (stores, dates, sexes).

With my mdx-query I can get members amount for a store based on year, months and sex.
The first total row at the bottom is the sum of Company A and Company B female amount and the second total row is for male.

Now I want to add a third total row with the sum of total row female and total row male (Total Female + Total Male).
How can I do this?

I cannot attach the image here because of less then 10 reputations, so I uploaded the screen dump to https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQbcl.png

Comment: Can you edit and paste the query in your question too?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a custom member into your `WITH` clause that is the sum of M and F, like this

```
WITH
 MEMBER [SEXES].[SEX].[MALE+FEMALE] AS
   [SEXES].[SEX].&[1] 
 + [SEXES].[SEX].&[2]
```

Then just add that new member into the set you have in the `SELECT` clause:

```
{
   [SEXES].[SEX].&[1], 
   [SEXES].[SEX].&[2],
   [SEXES].[SEX].[MALE+FEMALE]
}
```